# Logarithm of Brownian Motion - local martingale but not martingale.

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

I have just started studying stochastic analysis and I am stuck on trying to show that for $B$ a two-dimensional Brownian motion, $\ X_t=\log\left(\left|B_t\right|\right)_t$ is a local martingale but not a martingale.

I saw people trying to tackle such questions using Ito integrals, but being one of the first things in my course, I imagine there is an elementary way to think about this, and I would be very curious about it? In particular, what sequence of stopping times should I use? 
Intuitively I imagine it has to do with the fact that the stopped process is uniformly integrable, so we can apply Doob's stopping theorem.

I would be extremely grateful if someone could please explain these details to me? Thank you very much for your time and help!!

Comment: Well, the process starts at time $t=0$ at $-\infty$, so there is no chance that this becomes integrable (even by stopping).

Comment: @saz I really apologize if I am missing something, but for it to be a local martingale, I have to find a sequence of stopping time ${\tau_n}$  such that the stopped processes $X_(\tau_n)*1_{\tau_n>0}$  are martingales, so in particular they have  to be integrable?  Do you mind explaining to me what I misunderstood?

Answer (score 4):

Because of the problem pointed out by @saz, let's assume that $B_0=x\not=0$. For convenience only, I'll suppose that $|x|=1$. It follows easily from Ito's formula that $X_t$ is a local martingale with $X_0=0$. If $X$ were a martingale then you would have $\Bbb E[X_t]=0$ for all $t>0$. But unless I am mistaken, a calculation using polar coordinates shows that 
$$
\Bbb E[X_t]={\sqrt{2\pi}\over t}\int_0^1\log(1/ r)e^{-r^2/2t}r\,dr,
$$
which is strictly positive.

Comment: I am very, very sorry, but it is not so obvious to me how it follows directly that it is a local martingale. Would mind spelling it out a little? Moreover, would you be able to explain to me which sequence of stopping times In would need to use, if I wanted to show this by definition? Thank you very much for everything!

Comment: The function $u(y):=\log|y|$ is smooth on $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ and satisfies $\Delta u(y)=0$ for all $y\not=0$. Because Brownian motion in $\Bbb R^2$ doesn't hit the origin, a convenient sequence of stopping times for showing that  $u(B_t)$ is a local martingale is given by $\tau_n:=\inf\{t: |B_t|>n\}\wedge\inf\{t:|B_t|<1/n\}$. Notice that both $u$ and $\nabla u$ are bounded and continuous on each annulus $\{y\in\Bbb R^2:1/n\le x\le n\}$. Apply Ito's formula to the stopped process $u(B_{t\wedge \tau_n})$ to conclude that $X_{t\wedge\tau_n}$ is a (bounded) martingale, for each $n$.