# Why is $\ln(\det(B^TB))$ a local martingale for B a Brownian matrix?

Tags: logarithms, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, random-matrices, local-martingales

I am studying stochastic calculus on my own so this should be a basic question. I saw in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01259552 the statement that for $B$ an brownian matrix (with independent brownian motions as components), $\ln(\det(B^TB))$ is a local martingale.

I understand that I could use Itos formula to rewrite it as a integral over brownian motion since ln is twice differentiable, but I have trouble formulating the exact properties satisfied so I can conclude that $\ln(\det(B^TB))$ is a local martingale. I am mostly confused because in the determinant I have squares of brownian motions. I feel like this should be pretty basic and since I am not able, I would appreciate every detail.

This could be related to [Logarithm of Brownian Motion - local martingale but not martingale.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063390/logarithm-of-brownian-motion-local-martingale-but-not-martingale)

Edit: I have just realized, that I have not given the whole statement, namely the author of the paper looks at $t_0 = \inf (t: det(B^TB) = 0)$ and says that $\ln(\det(B^TB))$ is a local martingale on the interval $[0,t_0)$. I have not seen that processes are local martingales on some interval of a stopping time. Is then the conclusion that it is a local martingale on the interval trivial because on this interval the logarithm is twice differentiable and therefore itos formula is applicable?

Comment: Best to understand the one dimensional case first where the determinant is very simple: $\ln B^2_t$. The problem is that $B_t$ can become zero or negative. So we can only write this as $2\ln |B_t|$. Now we need Tanaka's formula (not Ito's) to handle this non differentiable function.

Comment: If $B$ is a real Brownian motion, $2\ln|B_t|$ is not a local martingale. It works only if you take a complex Brownian motion. My guess is that you have to precise that you work with a complex martingale and to replace $B^\top$ with $B^* = \overline{B}^\top. $